# birt merge cells together when exporting to excel

Tags: java, report, birt, birt-emitter

I'm facing a problem with `birt report` , in the first column i have an image to display , when exporting to excel i see that there is a lot of merged cell together : see the picture below

[image]

NB:when exporting to excel i'm using an emitter

```
options = new EXCELRenderOption();
options.setOutputFormat("xls");
options.setOption(IRenderOption.EMITTER_ID, "org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.nativexls");
```

any help how to fix this please?